# Is there an excuse for not using tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I went to one company. It's some big international product on Ruby (as they say).

So first day I came there - I look at their code - and it has long methods (pagedown each, many nested if's, inline calls to external libraries - nightmare), and almost no tests.

They say company is on the market for a year or so, it has 20 programmers that all work on same product, but all I see for now is that part of them finds bugs, and other part randomly fixes those bugs (which they make themselves because they treat tests as something they don't have time to do).

Has anyone worked with such products?

I know how bad a program without tests and refactoring can get. But they ask me to learn the product better before making a decision. Am I not getting something?

Comment: Run. Run as far as you can.

Comment: That's what I think as well.

Comment: This is really an opinion question, though. Are you trying to use StackOverflow to complain about a product?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: No - I'm not complaining. Just asking.

Comment: Yes, but this is not the place for such questions. Please, read the FAQ first.

Comment: Well, I could tell stories ...   But this is OT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of excuses. None of them are valid. The problem also is that it is a slippery scale. Once you stop writing tests, or did not start writing tests, it is a hellish task to start adding tests to old code. Tests are documentation, and a lot of documentation is missing without tests. So you will not know why specific parts of code are there, or why they are (at first sight) that bad. Sometimes there is a good reason.

Tell your boss that a good way to learn the product is to write tests. Start with cucumber, because that way you do not need to know the insides of the application. Check your test coverage (e.g. with `simple_cov`). That gives nice measurable feedback (progress). Then focus on model tests.

Be the change. Educate. If that is not possible, draw your conclusions :)